# Subdivision method of triangulation

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics

Is there a standard name for the subdivision scheme for a 2d simplicial complex, in which each face is subdivided into 4 (similar triangles), and each edge in half?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen it called *midpoint subdivision*.

[image: midpoint subdivision]

(image from http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3177/subdivision_surface_theory.php)